# React Dynamically using Component Names

Tags: reactjs

I'm getting the following error:

```
Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component />
```

external components

```
import Comment from 'material-ui-icons/Comment'
import Attachment from 'material-ui-icons/Attachment'
import History from 'material-ui-icons/History'
import TrendingUp from 'material-ui-icons/TrendingUp'

        this.components = {
            comment: Comment,
            attachment: Attachment,
            history: History,
            trendingup: TrendingUp
        }
```

render:

```
                {this.menu.map((data, index) => (
                <span key={index}>
                    {dynamicClassName = this.state[data.value.class]}

                    <span
                        key={index}
                        id="historicalTestsColorBandTitle"
                        className={"mobileBottomBannerOptions "+dynamicClassName}
                        onClick={this.handleBannerOptionsClick.bind(this, data.value.type)}
                    >

                        {DynamicComponentName = this.components[data.value.icon]}

                        {!dynamicClassName &&
                        <div>
                            <table><tbody><tr>
                                <td>
                                    <DynamicComponentName
                                        className="mobileBottomBannerIcon"
                                    />
                                </td>
                            </tr></tbody></table>
                        </div>
                        }

                        {dynamicClassName &&
                        <div>
                            <table><tbody><tr>
                                <td>
                                    <DynamicComponentName
                                        className="mobileBottomBannerIcon"
                                    />
                                </td>
                                <td className="menuOptionTitle">
                                    {data.value.name}
                                </td>
                            </tr></tbody></table>
                        </div>
                        }
                    </span>
                </span>
            ))}
```

You can see 'DynamicComponentName' is where the component name is created. I need to use a method like this as the order of these components changes depending on the last one clicked.

The components display fine but I get the error message at the top...

Any advice on how to resolve the error message?

thankyou!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move your assignment out of JSX:

```
render() {
  const dynamicClass = this.state[data.value.class];
  const DynamicComponent = this.components[data.value.icon];

  return // ...
}
```

If you need to make your assignment inside of `map`, you can do that too:

```
this.menu.map((data, index) => {
  const dynamicClass = this.state[data.value.class];
  const DynamicComponent = this.components[data.value.icon];

  return // ...
})
```

Comment: I would but the map function above them is required... map is used in the JSX... they need to be dynamic with the map...

Comment: Luke is right, you need to move the assignment out of the `JSX`. In this case that means you also need to move your `map` out of the `JSX`. Do the logical stuff like assigning the dynamic class and component first, then return `JSX`

Comment: oh ok... I get you... so I would create an array externally and then use that say with the index of map inside the JSX... nice... really appreciated...